# Keyerror in Pandas 0.13.1 and python 2.7.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a csv file, one of the columns is "locations". when i try the below code, I am getting key error 'locations'. The code works fine on earlier versions of pandas. "places_count = list(data1['locations'])" is causing error. Does anyone know reason for this error.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data//datafile.csv')
data1 = data.groupby('locations').count()
places = list(data1.index)
places_count = list(data1['locations'])
```

Contents of datafile.csv:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
Name | locations | states
A    | Hyderabad | Andhra Pradesh
B    | Hyderabad | Andhra Pradesh
C    | Agartala  | Tripura
D    | Ahmedabad | Gujarat
+++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @FooBar says, it may be that your column names have spaces. You can fix that in your import with `data = pd.read_csv('tmpdat.csv', skipinitialspace=True)`.

However, your code still won't run because `data1` doesn't have a `locations` column since you've already grouped by `locations`. I'm not sure exactly what you want to do but, if you're trying to count the number of observations at each location, I'd recommend `data.locations.value_counts()` instead of a `groupby`.

Comment: thanks a tone dude. That really helped me. I made use of value_counts() instead of grouping.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code in Pandas `0.14` reading in through `read_clipboard()` and got the same error. 
However, upon further inspection, the column names I got had spaces. The following application worked without error:

```
data = data.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())
data.groupby('locations')
Out[408]: <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000000010CB5B70>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried it, it didn't work for me. I have removed spaces for column names even in the csv files.